# Parceljs build UMD

Tags: umd, parceljs

I am trying to build a module using the module-bundler ParcelJS. I would like this certain module to be import-friendly:

- it should be import friendly (ES6)
- It should be require friendly (Node)
- It should be script-src friendly (Browser)
- It should support the UMD convention...

I tried the following:

TestClass.js

```
export class TestClass {
  constructor(msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
    this.init();
  }
  init() {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
    <div class="message">${this.msg}</div>`);
  }
}
```

index.js (file that creates the bundle)

```
//import styling for TestClass
import styles from '../css/styles';

//import class TestClass library
import { TestClass } from './TestClass';

//export TestClass
export default TestClass;
```

Trying to create the universal bundle by running:
    parcel index.js --global TestClass

Is there someone who can give me more information/help on exporting modules using parceljs?

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```sh
parcel build index.js --global TestClass
```

Some CLI Options:

- `-d`: choose directory
- `-o`: output filename
- `--no-minify`
- `--global <GlobalName>`

---

If you want to watch and build at the time:

```sh
parcel watch build index.js --global TestClass
```